# Envío como método POST la temperatura de mi DEVKIT SigFox, pero tengo el error "Cannot Get /sigfox" en mi servidor Node JS

Tags: nodejs, express, arduino, http-post, http-get

Este es mi codigo Node JS:

```
import express from "express";
import pg from "pg";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { PORT, DB_USER, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASS, DB_PORT } from "./config.js";

const { Pool } = pg;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const pool = new Pool({
  user: DB_USER,
  host: DB_HOST,
  database: DB_NAME,
  password: DB_PASS,
  port: DB_PORT,
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios;`);
  const rows = result.rows;
  res.json(rows);
});

app.get("/sigfox", (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor iniciado en http://localhost:`, PORT);
});
```

Estoy tratando de enviar la temperatura de mi "SigFox DEVKIT" por método POST al servidor, pero cuando entro al servidor me sale el error "Cannot GET /sigfox".

Pero en Sigfox Backend CallBack me dice que envió los datos correctamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé por qué sucedió esto. Les muestro mi configuración de Callback en caso de que tenga algún problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Por qué sucedió eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?**

Anteriormente pensé que era porque estaba trabajando con un servidor local, pero ahora con un servidor alojado me sale el mismo error. Por favor, necesito ayuda.